# Tweepy and Twitter can't work together

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

EDIT: I managed to make Twitter work by using virtualenv. However, I would still like to resolve this issue.

I installed and used Tweepy successfully. However, when I try to use Twitter API only, I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'oauth'
```

The code I am using is from Mining the Social Web, 2nd edition:

```
import twitter

def oauth_login():
    # XXX: Go to http://twitter.com/apps/new to create an app and get values
    # for these credentials that you'll need to provide in place of these
    # empty string values that are defined as placeholders.
    # See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth for more information 
    # on Twitter's OAuth implementation.

    CONSUMER_KEY = ''
    CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
    OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
    OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

    auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                               CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

    twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
    return twitter_api
```

And the error is displayed after the following calls:

```
twitter_api = oauth_login() 
print twitter_api
```

I have oauth installed and I can't figure out what is going on. I need to have Tweepy installed since I have already written a huge chunk of code that works with Tweepy and I am guessing that the issue arises from having Tweepy installed.

Edit: the code in the book uses https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter

Comment: Please add a code example that makes the AttributeError appear. How do you install Tweepy?

Comment: added the code (of course, the actual code has all the keys)

Comment: Is your issue that you (need to) have python-twitter and Tweepy installed, and only with both being installed the error occurs? Just to make sure I understand your problem!

Comment: What I did to try to reproduce this: `pip install twitter tweepy` (not in a virtualenv), then write your sourcecode into a file, with the line `oauth_login()` added (to run the function). However, it runs without errors. Could you try `pip install --upgrade twitter tweepy` ? Maybe you have an old version...

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Tweepy, OAuth is performed by creating a new `OAuthHandler` instance - there is no `OAuth` class. Also, `OAuthHandler` resides in the `auth` package, not the `oauth` package. Finally, all four authentication keys are not passed to the constructor - the access token and access token secret are set using the `set_access_token` method.

The your code should look like this:

```
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
```